# Throwing exception as : Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, setstring

I am passing an array from one ViewController to another by `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.and i am retrieving array in second view controller and while i try to update a string value it throws an **Exception** as below

```
Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString
```

and below is my code. Not able to track what is the issue .

> > ```
> > NSMutableArray *sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
> > sampleArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"] copy];
> > NSString *commentCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"]objectAtIndex:Row]];
> > int cCount = [commentCount intValue];
> > [[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] objectAtIndex:Row]setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cCount+1]];
> > ```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't alloc init sampleArray just to override it the in next line. replace `NSMutableArray *sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` with `NSMutableArray *sampleArray;`

Comment: i tried all answers. bad luck. getting same exception. any other way ?

Comment: What kind of object is [sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] ? I guess it's an NSArray. What kind of objects contains this array?

Comment: Strings inside array. like :(
    6,
    0,
    0,
    35,
    3,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
)

Comment: [[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] objectAtIndex:Row] line returns you NSString which is nonmutable. So first make it as mutable then use it. For help See my answer below.

Comment: Stupid question:  **What line** was reported as causing the error???

Comment: Did you attempt to actually *read* the error message?  What does it say?

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, i can understand. it says i am updating Mutable Object to Imutable Object. But i can't track where is that part happening ?

Comment: Is says you're attempting change (mutate) an object that cannot be changed.  And you're doing it with `setString`.  Now, where in your code do you see `setString`?  And what kind of object is it operating on?

Comment: If `sampleArray` is an NSArray, why are you doing `valueForKey` on it?

Comment: There are at least 5 errors in the above code.  Please go back and learn the fundamentals a little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
    NSMutableArray *sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sampleArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"] copy];
    NSString *commentCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"]objectAtIndex:Row]];
    int cCount = [commentCount intValue];
    [[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] objectAtIndex:Row]setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cCount+1]];
```

1) You do

```
NSMutableArray *sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sampleArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"] copy];
```

The `[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]` constructs an empty mutable array.  The subsequent `sampleArray = [[[NSUserDefaults ...` *overwrites* the pointer set in the prior line with a pointer to a different array.  This is wasted motion (and creating an object is expensive).  Thankfully for you there is ARC, or it would also represent a leaked object.  It should be simply

```
 NSArray *sampleArray = [[NSUserDefaults ...
```

(Note it is **not** an NSMutableArray -- see below.)

2) You do

```
sampleArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"] copy];
```

The `copy` on the end unnecessarily takes the object returned by `objectForKey` and copies it.  Unless here were some possibility of unwanted concurrent modification of the original array (which is impossible in this case), this `copy` operation is completely unnecessary and again an expensive operation.

3) You do

```
NSString *commentCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"]objectAtIndex:Row]];
```

Doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",someValue]` simply (and expensively) creates a copy of `someValue`.  Again, this is totally unnecessary -- it only serves to make your statement longer and more confusing.

4) You do

```
[[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] objectAtIndex:Row]setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cCount+1]];
```

Let's take that (unnecessarily) long statement apart:

```
NSArray* temp1 = [sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"];
```

This is using "key-value" coding and will examine every NSDictionary in the array and ask it for any "totalComments" element.

```
NSString* temp2 = [temp1 objectAtIndex:Row];
```

This takes the result from `valueForKey` and examines only the `Row` element.  Though it's hard to know for sure without knowing how "commentsArray" is constructed, very likely it would have worked just as well (and more clearly) to access the `Row` element of `sampleArray` and then request the `totalCommnts` value from the resulting NSDictionary.  This would have been faster and clearer.

What you now have in temp2 is an NSString.  You now effectively execute

```
[temp2 setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cCount+1]];
```

Of course, your problem is now that an NSString is immutable, so an exception occurs.  If you want to change it you must have an NSMutableString.  But you cannot simply "install" one of those in the `temp1` array, since [all values returned by NSUserDefaults are immutable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults), including `sampleArray`, `temp1`, and `temp2`.  (And, no, they cannot be made mutable by simply changing the declarations.)

So you're kind of stuck.  You need to totally redesign this function.

Comment: Ok, then again i have to set this updated temp2 string back to that array. that is my problem

Comment: Ok, No Probs. Thanks for you all.i achieved this Process completely by different way.

Comment: @Grey_Code - You can't set temp2 back into the dictionary because the dictionary is immutable (and because you don't know which dictionary to update due to how you found temp2 in the first place).  If the string were mutable that would not matter, since updating the string pointed by temp2 would update the string in the dictionary.  But of course the string is not mutable either.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your code line

```
sampleArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"] copy];
```

because copy return non mutable array so you have to do like

```
sampleArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *sampleArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"commentsArray"]];
NSString *commentCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"]objectAtIndex:Row]];
int cCount = [commentCount intValue];
NSMutableString *myMutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] objectAtIndex:Row]];
[myMutableString setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cCount+1]];
```

Comment: "[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"] objectAtIndex:Row]".  Could you describe this line please. @Grey_Code

Comment: [[[sampleArray valueForKey:@"totalComments"]objectAtIndex:Row]setString:myMutableString];

Comment: Replace this line with 2 lines in my answer.

Comment: it will get string like if Row=2, then "0" is detected from Array. at this place i'm incrementing the count. and saving back the updated array to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Ok.next i have to update the incremented count string to array and save back to nsuserdefaults.

Comment: Could you show me the content format of sampleArray. It'll help me to make my answer more help full to you. @Grey_Code

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are passing a mutable array value to a immutable string.Try changing NSString to NSMutableString.Hopefully this helps